# ZF2 route with prefix in not working for default

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2, zend-route

I want add crm as prefix of CRM module.

This is router section in my module.config.php

```
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(          
            'calendar' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/crm/calendar[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Crm\Controller\Calendar',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

When i use test.dev/crm/calendar/index is working properly. But it is not working for test.dev/crm/calendar . I couldn't find any issue.

When i use `'route'    => '/calendar[/:action][/:id]',` i can use test.dev/calendar. But i need use prefix. How can i do it?

Comment: Your route config is correct, it must be something else. why is it 'not working'? What error do you get?

Comment: config is correct. Because it is working in some url. When i use /crm/calender it is not redirect to related action.

Comment: try `'route'    => '/crm/calendar[/:action[/:id]]'`

Comment: You say you aren't redirected to the right action, but is another route matching instead, or do you get an exception? This would help us narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route configuration is correct. This route had over write from another module route. That's the issue. ZF2 has not easy way to check all routes and paths.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be that you have to add  `'may_terminate' => true,`

So your route definition will look like this:

```
'calendar' => array(
    'type'    => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/crm/calendar[/:action][/:id]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id'     => '[0-9]+',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Crm\Controller\Calendar',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
),
```

Try if that works.

Otherwise you can also split it and make crm to a literal route.

```
'crm' => array(
    'type' => 'literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/crm',
    ),
    'may_terminate' => false,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'calendar' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/calendar[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Crm\Controller\Calendar',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

But this last solution means that you will always have to route to `crm/calendar`

Comment: @Asuraya I just tried in my own application and it works... Are you sure you you make no typos and that your router is not overwritten somewhere else in your application?

Comment: Yes. That is the issue. crm route had override from another module. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As seen configs should correct.
Did you tried without last / (test.dev/crm/calendar, not test.dev/crm/calendar/)